# Angular - Use Injector for Router in Service

Tags: angular, router

I try to implement an error service which need to use the Angular Router methods in this class. And all I can found is to insert the Router class into my service by using Injector method of Angular.

So, I do grab the Injector object with dependency injection in my constructor of my serice class:

```js
Import { ErrorHandler, Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
 
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class RequestErrorHandlerService implements ErrorHandler {
 
    private _router: any

    constructor(
        private injector: Injector
    ) {}

    handleError(error) {

        const router = this.injector.get(Router);
        ...
        router.navigate(['/login']);   
    }
}
```

And I try to use injector.get() for to get the Router object. But all I get is an error

> Uncaught TypeError: this.injector.get is not a function

So, I think I forgot something. But didn´t get the problem. Why does this not works?

Do have somebody a tip for me, or an link to a tutorial which realy works with Angular Version 8 or higher?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Recently faced same issue, and had similar code that you had mentioned.

Check if you have mentioned the `ErrorHandler` in app module providers like below:

```
{
   provide: ErrorHandler,
   useClass: RequestErrorHandlerService
}
```

and **not** like below (Previously, in app module providers, when I had mentioned ErrorHandler as given below, it didn't work for me)

```
{
   provide: ErrorHandler,
   useClass: RequestErrorHandlerService,
   deps: [APP_INITIALIZER]
}
```

---

Anyways, below is some code snippets that worked for me, which might be useful.

`app-error-handler.ts`:

```
@Injectable()
export class AppErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

    constructor(private injector: Injector) {}

    handleError(error: Error) {
        console.log('Client side - ' + error.message);
        const router = this.injector.get(Router);
        router.navigate(['login']);
    }
}
```

`app.module.ts`:

```
@NgModule({
  // ...
  providers: [
    {
      provide: ErrorHandler,
      useClass: AppErrorHandler
    }
  // ...
  ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply inject the Router via the constructor:

```
export class RequestErrorHandlerService implements ErrorHandler {
    constructor(
        private router: Router
    ) {}

    handleError(error) {
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);   
    }
}
```

Comment: That what I thought too. But with that I get the error: this.router.navigate is not a function

Comment: Did you import the RouterModule in the AppModule (or at least ComponentModule)?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just like this ?

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private router: router) {}

handleError(error) {
  this.router.navigate(['/login']);   
}
```